# ¿Como filtrar registros en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de filtrar un conjunto de registros con las siguientes dos validaciones:

- Si F o NC TIENEN Importe(Columna 18) = 0 , el que tenga importe(Columna 18) 0 debe tener codigo(Columna20) 1 o 2
- Si F y NC tiene Importe(Columna 18) > 0, el codigo(Columna20) deben ser iguales

Donde cada numero de boleto tiene un registro con F y NC, es por eso que son dos por cada uno.

Estos son mis registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera validación la logro obtener de la siguiente forma:

```sql
    select 
    A.[Columna 1]
    , A.[Columna 6]
    , A.[Columna 8]
    , A.[Columna 11]
    , A.[Columna 13]
    , A.[Columna 16]
    , A.[Columna 17]
    , A.[Columna 18]
    , A.[Columna 20] 
    from 
    tblPasoPraxis as A
    where 
    A.[Columna 1] = 'T' 
    and A.[Columna 8] = 'EXCA'  
    and (A.[Columna 18] in ('.00', '0.00') 
    and A.[Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F') 
    and A.[Columna 20] = '0')
```

Y este es mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda validación es la que me esta costando un poco de trabajo y la trate de realizar de la siguiente forma:
Donde aqui traté de hacer dos join a la misma tabla y dandole un valor a la columna 17 para cada una, una con el valor de 'F' y a la otra 'NC' para hacer la comparación de que si son diferen

```sql
    select 
    A.[Columna 1]
    , A.[Columna 6]
    , A.[Columna 8]
    , A.[Columna 11]
    , A.[Columna 13]
    , A. [Columna 16]
    , A.[Columna 17]
    , A.[Columna 18]
    , A.[Columna 20] 
    from 
    tblPasoPraxis as A
    join tblPasoPraxis as B on B.[Columna 1] = A.[Columna 1] and B.[Columna 17] = 'F'
    join tblPasoPraxis as C on C.[Columna 1] = A.[Columna 1] and C.[Columna 17] = 'NC'
    where 
    A.[Columna 1] = 'T' 
    and A.[Columna 8] = 'EXCA'  
    and (
    A.[Columna 18] in ('.00', '0.00') 
    and A.[Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F') 
    and A.[Columna 20] = '0') 
    or (A.[Columna 18] > '.00' and C.[Columna 20] = B.[Columna 20]
    )
    group by A.[Columna 1], A.[Columna 6], A.[Columna 8], A.[Columna 11], A.[Columna 13], A.[Columna 16], A.[Columna 17], A.[Columna 18], A.[Columna 20]
```

Con esa consulta no estoy llegando al resultado que quiero, los registros que debe arrojarme son los siguientes:
Ya que son los que no cumplen las reglas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan orientar en mi error o que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `MIN/MAX OVER` y `COUNT OVER` con una expresión condicionál para colectar todas las informaciones necesarias:

```
select
  [Columna 1], [Columna 6], [Columna 8], [Columna 11], [Columna 13],
  [Columna 16], [Columna 17], [Columna 18], [Columna 20]
from
(
  select
    tblpasopraxis.*,
    min([Columna 18]) over win as min_col_18,
    min([Columna 20]) over win as min_col_20,
    max([Columna 20]) over win as max_col_20,
    count(case when [Columna 18] = 0 and [Columna 20] not in (1,2) then 1 end)
      over win as cnt_regla_1_violada
  from tblpasopraxis
  where [Columna 1] = 'T'
    and [Columna 8] = 'EXCA'
    and [Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F')
  window win as (partition by [Columna 6])
) examinado
where cnt_regla_1_violada > 0
or (min_col_18 > 0 and min_col_20 <> max_col_20)
order by [Columna 6], [Columna 17];
```

Si tu versión de SQL Server todavía no permite `WINDOW win AS ...`, tienes que remover esta linea y sustituir todas las `OVER win` con `OVER (PARTITION BY [Columna 6])`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Thorsten.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    A.[Columna 1]
    , A.[Columna 6]
    , A.[Columna 8]
    , A.[Columna 11]
    , A.[Columna 13]
    , A.[Columna 16]
    , A.[Columna 17]
    , case
    when A.[Columna 18] = 0 then A.[Columna 20] 
    when A.[Columna 18] > 0 then A.[Columna 18] 
    end as 'importe'
    , A.[Columna 20] 
from 
    tblPasoPraxis as A    
where 
    A.[Columna 1] = 'T' 
    and A.[Columna 8] = 'EXCA'  
    and (A.[Columna 18] in ('.00', '0.00') 
    and A.[Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F') 
    and A.[Columna 20] = '0')
```

por lo tanto cuando `Colummna 18` es `0` tome `Colummna 20`:

> when A.[Columna 18] = 0 then A.[Columna 20]

y cuando `Colummna 18` es mayor a `0` tome `Colummna 18`:

> when A.[Columna 18] > 0 then A.[Columna 18]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportacion Dav pero solo me da la primera validacion y requiero las dos que comento en mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

prácticamente he adjuntado la misma tabla pero a la columna 17 posee valor 'F', espero  alguien obtenga un mejor resultado u otra forma de lograrlo.

```
select 
   A.[Columna 1], A.[Columna 6], A.[Columna 8], A.[Columna 11], A.[Columna 
   13], A.[Columna 16], A.[Columna 17], A.[Columna 20] 
from tblPasoPraxis as A  
join tblPasoPraxis as B on A.[Columna 6] = B.[Columna 6] and B.[Columna 17] 
= 'F'
where A.[Columna 1] = 'T' and A.[Columna 8] = 'EXCA' 
  and (A.[Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F') and A.[Columna 18] in ('.00', '0.00') 
  and A.[Columna 18] = '.00' and A.[Columna 20] = 0)
  or (A.[Columna 17] in ('NC', 'F') and A.[Columna 18] > '.00' and A. 
  [Columna 20] <> B.[Columna 20])
group by A.[Columna 1], A.[Columna 6], A.[Columna 8], A.[Columna 11], A. 
  [Columna 13], A.[Columna 16], A.[Columna 17], A.[Columna 18], A.[Columna 
  20], B.[Columna 20]
```